# Validating JWT token before every API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jwt, mern

Currently I am working on a project in React which has protected routes (protected by JWT authorization).

Some pages are rendered differently, based on the user's permissions.
These permissions are encrypted in the token payload.

Since JWT tokens can be decrypted and altered, users could—*in theory*—alter the token in order to gain access to a page they really shouldn't have access to.
Because the token lost its validity, the backend server won't process any requests by that specific user, so no damage can be done.

I still don't want the user to be able to gain access to protected pages just by altering the JWT token. My solution to this problem would be to send a request to an endpoint which validates the token.
Depending on the endpoint's response a second API call would be made, which then would return the required data for the protected page.
If the validation endpoint returns that the token is no longer valid, the user would be redirected to a login page.

---

Login > Go to protected page > Validate token > Access protected page

Login > Alter received JWT token > Go to protected route > Validate token > Error > Login page

---

Now my question: is this a good approach to this problem? Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you very much in advance. :)

Comment: JWT validation should be done by a middleware, so you don’t have to worry about tampered JWT token holders having access to privileged pages.

Comment: @Terry Are you talking about Express middleware or React / Redux Middleware?

Answer (score 0):

JWT token has 3 parts:

- Header
- Payload
- Signature

Signature is used to verify Header and Payload is not changed. So the attacker needs to create a new signature for the altered token. It is -in theory- nearly impossible to create a valid signature without your secret key.

The extra step you proposed doesn't do anything. If your client can alter the key successfully, she can easily bypass this step and make an API call to protected resources.

The token validation step should be done in the backend.

- Login(front end) > Go to protected route(front end) > Validate token(back end) > Return protected page(back end)
- Login(front end) > Alter received JWT token(front end) > Go to protected route(front end) > Validate token(back end) >  return error(back end)> Login page(front end)

**Edit**
To hide views from users in the front end:

- You can validate JWT in the front end(using the public key) without making a request if you are using an asymmetrical key.
- Or as you mentioned, you can create an endpoint to validate tokens.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I of course validate the token in the backend. I was talking about how the use might temper with the payload. My front-end React app would read the user's fake permission and grant them access to the view (not the actual data from my backend API). My issue is that I don't want users to see the view, which is why I proposed an API endpoint for validating the token before even granting access to the protected page.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question at first. If you are using an asymmetric key you can validate the token in the frontend as well(Using your public key). Having such an endpoint is also common in microservices.

Comment: Great! I'll implement a token validation endpoint then. Many thanks for your help. :)